# How do I get the index of an element in a list that I'm cycling through?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

Im trying to brute force a caesar cypher for a school project, and am trying to iterate through a list (the dictionary), to do this I've used itertools to make the list 'infinte' so shifting x by 4 will return a instead of an error.

However: when using itertools.cycle(dictionary) i get the error "AttributeError: 'itertools.cycle' object has no attribute 'index'"

I'm not sure why this is happening as it would imply that I cannot index an 'infinite' list.

Here is some basic code that gives the error:

```
from itertools import cycle

dictionary=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
dict=cycle(dictionary)

print(dict.index('c'))
```

I can provide my entire program if it helps (sorry its a bit messy and I haven't got around to commenting it yet.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: you can also approach ASCII character conversion to ceaser cypher algorithm, it can easy as compare to this.

Comment: Note that `cycle` does not produce a list at all, but a more general object called an _iterator_.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here.

The first is just to save the original list, and index into that:

```py
chars = list('abc')
chars_cycle = itertools.cycle(chars)
for i, c in enumerate(chars_cycle):
    print(c, chars.index(c))
    if i > 14:
        break
```

Another option is to include the index in the cycle itself:

```py
chars = list('abc')
chars_cycle = itertools.cycle(enumerate(chars))
for i, c in chars_cycle:
    print(i, c)
    if i > 14:
        break
```

It's worth spending a while to understand how these two examples differ.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, from what I understand by enumerating the list this program will produce the 'infinite' list I'm looking for, and give each element in it a number.
However the thing I'm still trying to solve is if I want to shift the letter x by 4, my current program finds x's number (24), and adds on the amount it is to be shifted, using one of your examples will i be able to find the new letter or will I have to do some maths to make the number 4 again (to get a from x)?
I can give my entire program if it helps to understand where this solution will be implemented.

Comment: Use the modulo operator for that.